# Can `dmn {DirichletMultinomial}` be run on multiple cpu cores in R?

Tags: r, multithreading, cpu-cores, dirichlet

I analyse microbiome data using

```
library(phyloseq)
library(microbiome)
library(DirichletMultinomial)
```

and several other libraries. Fitting Dirichlet-Multinomial models to count data `dmn {DirichletMultinomial}` takes quite a long time. Can the computation be run on multiple cpu cores in R.
I tried:

```
dat <- abundances(pseq)
count <- as.matrix(t(dat))
fit <- lapply(1:25, dmn, count = count, verbose=TRUE)
```

replacing with:

```
library(parallel)
numCores <- detectCores()
...
fit <- mclapply(1:25, dmn, count = count, verbose=TRUE, mc.cores = numCores)
```

but it returns errorWarning message:
**In mclapply(1:25, dmn, count = count, verbose = TRUE, mc.cores = numCores) :
all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code**

I am using

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
> detectCores()
[1] 4
```

Can anyone help?

Best regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as illustrated in the vignette http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DirichletMultinomial/inst/doc/DirichletMultinomial.pdf section 2 and in your code it is possible to run on multiple cores.

Probably what is happening is that there are errors for some of the values of X; what is the value of fit? Also, one might try

```
library(BiocParallel)
fit <- bplapply(1:25, dmm, count, BPPARAM = MulticoreParam(numCores))
```

`fit` will be an object that can be queried (see the BiocParallel vignette available from https://bioconductor.org/packages/BiocParallel) for more error information.

Comment: Dear Martin, it must has been an issue with packages. I upgraded them and it works now. All cores in use now. Thanks!